# Grass-roots, localized, helping local people to develop?

Tags: synonyms

I am working on a project that helps people to develop green energy at a small scale, grassroots level.

Please suggest other words to describe this kind of social/technology change, for the ordinary people, localized change and small projects.

Answer (score 2):

'Local effort', 'community-based', 'independent', 'local initiative' are a few descriptors that come to mind.

Comment: Fantastic, great suggestions Listener.

Answer (score 1):

While

- ... a project that helps people to develop green energy **on a domestic scale** ...

refers in the first instance to individual households, it's broadened to include small neighbourhoods.

> - Some renewable energy technologies are well suited to domestic-scale use, particularly solar (either for heating water or for generating
>   electricity), heat pumps and biomass.

[[{UK} Centre for Sustainable Energy; CSE](https://www.cse.org.uk/advice/renewable-energy)]

> - There are also domestic-scale wind power and micro hydro – these are less common and they need specific locations to perform well.

[[Energy Saving Trust {UK}](https://energysavingtrust.org.uk/are-home-renewables-right-you/)]

> - As well as being used on a domestic scale, there are also several solar farms in the UK.

[[The Green Age](https://www.thegreenage.co.uk/an-introduction-to-renewables/)]

Similarly [bolding mine],

> - energy systems **on a neighbourhood scale**

[[MDPI](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/14/14/4314/htm)]